# Regex: remove double parenthesis but preserve singles

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a bunch of co-ordinate data coming back in the following format:

```
TYPE ((lat long, lat long), (lat long, lat long), (lat long))
```

I'm trying and failing at creating a regex that will remove anything except digits, spaces, commas, hypens, and SINGLE parenthesis; I can't for the life of me figure out how to remove double parenthesis but not single. I don't need to replace the double parenthesis with singles, just remove them.

What I've come up with so far is:

```
preg_replace('/[^0-9,.-\s\(\)]/', '', $val);
```

But this removes ALL brackets, which is not what I want, because I then have to explode() it based on those brackets. I've been trying with lookahead/lookbehind assertions but can't quite seem to get it right...

Comment: Just replace `((` with `(` and `))` with `)`. Why not?

Comment: That was my first thought, but it doesn't work for reasons well beyond my regex skill - neither `\(\(` or `((` replaces anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WIthout using any lookahead you can use this:

```
$s = 'TYPE ((lat long, lat long 234), (lat long, 999 lat long), (0 lat long))';
$r=preg_replace(array('/\(\s*\(/', '/\)\s*\)/', '/[^\d,.\s-()]/'), array('(', ')', ''), $s);
//=>  ( ,   234), ( , 999  ), (0  )
```

**EDIT: To remove double `((` or `))` use this code:**

```
$r = preg_replace('/\(\s*\(|\)\s*\)|[^\d,.\s-()]/', '', $s);
```

Comment: I don't mind using a lookahead/behind, I just can't get the ruddy thing to work =P

Comment: Above is a working solution, if for some reason it doesn't work for you then I guess your input is very different from given example. Post an example for which it doesn't work and I will try to alter the regex.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting the 3rd characters in there from, a sample set of data looks like

`((-43.890034454756574 169.0482307246851, -43.89005002907812 169.04822585031314, -43.89032379439251 169.04817474921765), (-43.890497944460435 169.04817437759846, -43.8906828999036 169.0482017322998, -43.89094407765449 169.0482852643153, -43.89119798264138 169.04841990476916, -43.89142707994269 169.04859775596108, -43.89172247950604 169.04890842219487, -43.892400348205 169.04972956701974, -43.89261320453715 169.04997906880197))`

Comment: With your new input my preg_replace is giving this: `(-43.890034454756574 169.0482307246851, -43.89005002907812 169.04822585031314, -43.89032379439251 169.04817474921765), (-43.890497944460435 169.04817437759846, -43.8906828999036 169.0482017322998, -43.89094407765449 169.0482852643153, -43.89119798264138 169.04841990476916, -43.89142707994269 169.04859775596108, -43.89172247950604 169.04890842219487, -43.892400348205 169.04972956701974, -43.89261320453715 169.04997906880197)` Is this not expected?

Comment: Apart from the brackets on the start and end, it's as expected. However I'd like to avoid passing preg_replace() an array of regexs if at all possible; this code is looped over tens of thousands of times with data sets containing up to a thousand co-ords each (the bits inside the inner brackets), so if I can get it down to one regex equation it'd be much appreciated....

Comment: So do you want `"(("` to become `""` ?